# How to prevent neo4j MERGE from creating duplicate relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to create nodes and relationships if they do not exist. I do not know ahead of time if anything in the DB exists.

This is my initial query:

```
MERGE (t:type { name: 'aaa'})
MERGE (m:model { name: 'bbb'})
MERGE (r:region {name: 'ccc'})
MERGE (p:param {name: 'ddd'})
MERGE (i:init {value: 123})
MERGE (u:forecast {url: 'http://something.png'})
MERGE (t)-[:HAS]-(m)-[:HAS]-(r)-[:HAS]-(p)-[:HAS]-(i)-[:HAS]-(u)
```

This correctly produces a graph like this:
[image: first graph output]

Then I run this query again, but this time I change the name of the "model" object to "bbc" (instead of "bbb"):

```
MERGE (t:type { name: 'aaa'})
MERGE (m:model { name: 'bbc'})
MERGE (r:region {name: 'ccc'})
MERGE (p:param {name: 'ddd'})
MERGE (i:init {value: 123})
MERGE (u:forecast {url: 'http://something.png'})
MERGE (t)-[:HAS]-(m)-[:HAS]-(r)-[:HAS]-(p)-[:HAS]-(i)-[:HAS]-(u)
```

Now, however, my graph looks like this:
[image: second graph]

Everything looks correct except for the three duplicated relationships.
I realize that `MATCH` will create the whole path if it does not exist. There must be some way to avoid creating duplicate relationships, though.

I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MERGE` statement checks if the pattern as a whole already exists or not. So, if there is one node different, the whole pattern is determined as non-existent and all relationships are created.

The solution is to split this `MERGE` statement into multiple, i.e. one `MERGE` for each relationship:

```sql
MERGE (t)-[:HAS]-(m)-[:HAS]-(r)-[:HAS]-(p)-[:HAS]-(i)-[:HAS]-(u)
```

becomes

```sql
MERGE (t)-[:HAS]-(m)
MERGE (m)-[:HAS]-(r)
MERGE (r)-[:HAS]-(p)
MERGE (p)-[:HAS]-(i)
MERGE (i)-[:HAS]-(u)
```